# Azure KQL list filtering

Tags: azure, kql, azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer, azure-analytics

I'm trying to filter a list by another list.

The objective is to get a list of all apps on a server, that doesn't have any logging against it. So I've created 2 variables, `appsInServer` which lists all the apps in the server, and
`appsBeingLogged` that lists all the apps being logged.

Then I'm just trying to filter out the apps from `appsInServer` that appear in `appsBeingLogged`.

Individually the first 2 queries to generate the list all works as expected, but the last query to filter the list errors

```sql
let appsInServer = arg("").resources
| where type == 'microsoft.web/sites' and properties.serverFarmId contains ('ASP-CPRD-CardiffApp-Hybrid01')
| extend serverName = case(properties.serverFarmId contains ('ASP-CPRD-CardiffApp-Hybrid01'), 'Hybrid01', 'Unkown')
| project  Name = tolower(tostring(name)); 
let appsBeingLogged = AppPerformanceCounters 
| extend Name=replace_string(tostring(split(_ResourceId, "/")[-1]), "appi-cprd-", "")
| where ((Category == "Process" and Counter == "% Processor Time Normalized") or Name == "processCpuPercentage")
| summarize by Name
| sort by Name
| project Name = strcat("app-cprd-", tolower(Name));
appsInServer
| where Name !in~ (appsBeingLogged)
| summarize by Name
| sort by Name
| project Name;
```

The error I get isn't very useful -
[image]

---

I know filtering by a list should work because this query works as expected -

```sql
let appsInServer = arg("").resources
| where type == 'microsoft.web/sites' and properties.serverFarmId contains ('ASP-CPRD-CardiffApp-Hybrid01')
| extend serverName = case(properties.serverFarmId contains ('ASP-CPRD-CardiffApp-Hybrid01'), 'Hybrid01', 'Unkown')
| project  Name = tolower(tostring(name)); 
AppPerformanceCounters 
| extend Name=replace_string(tostring(split(_ResourceId, "/")[-1]), "appi-cprd-", "")
| where ((Category == "Process" and Counter == "% Processor Time Normalized") or Name == "processCpuPercentage")
| where strcat("app-cprd-", tolower(Name)) in~ (appsInServer)
| summarize AvgCPUPercentage = sum(todouble(Value)) / count() by _ResourceId, Name
| sort by  AvgCPUPercentage
| project Name, round(AvgCPUPercentage, 2)
```

Comment: Are you sure issue is happening while filtering the Name only. Can you check executing the data of `appsInServer` and `appsBeingLogged` separately and check?

Comment: @Aswin ye both are working fine and the data is formatted correctly. I've copied the output of both to excel and can see ones that are matching and ones that are missing

Comment: I tried with sample data and it works;

Comment: @Aswin you mind sharing the sample that worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a bug in the `!in~`, converted the above query to use a join instead and it all works -

Here is the final query -

```sql
let appsInServer = arg("").resources
    | where type == 'microsoft.web/sites' and properties.serverFarmId contains ('ASP-CPRD-CardiffApp-Hybrid01')
    | extend serverName = case(properties.serverFarmId contains ('ASP-CPRD-CardiffApp-Hybrid01'), 'Hybrid01', 'Unkown')
    | project Name = tolower(tostring(name)); 
let appsBeingLogged = AppPerformanceCounters 
    | extend Name=replace_string(tostring(split(_ResourceId, "/")[-1]), "appi-cprd-", "")
    | summarize by Name
    | sort by Name
    | project Name = strcat("app-cprd-", tolower(Name));
appsInServer
    | join kind=anti (appsBeingLogged) on $left.Name == $right.Name
    | extend Name=replace_string(Name, "app-cprd-", "")
    | summarize by Name
    | sort by Name asc
    | project Name
```